# How to extract data from Google Calendar and show in plain text

Tags: text, google-calendar-api

I would like to extract the data and event name from a google calendar then show it as plain text. When ever the calendar is updated I would like the text to reflect this. It will be a part of a web site that I am working on.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GData apis are what you're looking for. There are APIs for .NET, PHP, and Java at least (having used all, they are all fine)[1]. I have used the Zend Framework's implementation [2] to great success making a timeclock application totaling the hours the members in our organization recorded on their Google calendars, and the .NET framework is just as good. For a website, this is the way to go.

There is also a nifty command line tool, though I have not has as much success with it (Both *nix and Windows command line, though of course you'll have much more processing power in *nix ;))

[1] http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html

[2] http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html

[3] http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/

[Edit]

The project I mentioned for building a timeclock is available at http://code.google.com/p/gcaltimeclock/
The files you are probably most interested in are  http://code.google.com/p/gcaltimeclock/source/browse/application/controllers/calendars.php and http://code.google.com/p/gcaltimeclock/source/browse/application/views/calendars/timesheets.php

Comment: I was hoping to find some code already out there for what I want. I keep searching around and cant find anything. I have a public google calendar that I want to parse the upcoming event dates & titles and post them on a web page.